# How to put a legend inside a loop with one by one data point (or outside) in Python?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, legend

In matplotlib, I am using a loop to plot a graph, with each step only plotting one data point (X[index], Y[index]) with a specific color C[index], so that it will assign a color to each point. In total, I use 8 colors to represent my data points, so I hope I can have a legend with these 8 colors and each one represents one meaning.

This is my code. Thanks for help. : )

```
for index in range(0,len(X)):
  plt.plot(X[index],Y1[index], marker = 'o', markersize = 10, color = C[index])  
  plt.xlabel("the percentage of students' credit hours found in instructor data", fontsize=14, color ="blue")
  plt.ylabel("total number of writing assinments", fontsize=14, color="blue")
  plt.axis([0, 100, 0, max(Y1)]) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: You'll have to read the manual for whatever module you are using to plot these graphs. Something you didn't even say what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example straight from the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot):

> The kwargs can be used to set line properties (any property that has a set_* method). You can use this to **set a line label (for auto legends)**, linewidth, anitialising, marker face color, etc. Here is an example:

```
    plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)
    plot([1,2,3], [1,4,9], 'rs',  label='line 2')
    axis([0, 4, 0, 10])
    legend()
```

So, if you set the `label` property for each line, you should just be able to call `legend()` afterwards and it will automagically generate the legend with appropriate labels.

If you want to do something fancier with the legend, they also have [documentation for that](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: Thanks. I got some ideas. :)